# Extracting dgz and/or zip2 compression files stored as binary in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I am pulling binary data of `.doc` and `.pdf` compressed files out of a database. I need to be able to extract these preferably from the stream and then save them to a file location. I do not have the compressed file extension, but I have the compression methods. They are `zip`, `zip2`, and `dgz`. I have virtually no experience in the realm of compression. I have never even heard of `dgz`.
I can pull the data and write it to a file location, but I cannot extract it appropriately.
I would appreciate any help from someone smarter than myself.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '12345'";
DataSet ds = ExecuteQuery(sql, "Document"); //This simply queries the data base
byte[] myBytes = new byte[0];
myBytes = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["document"];

// Need to extract the stream here

StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter("../file.pdf");
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(sWriter.BaseStream);
writer.Write(myBytes);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Check out Seven Zip Sharp (https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) it supports a wide variety of formats (I can't verify dgz, not familiar with that either) but it's really easy to use, and supports decompressing from a stream directly. It's documentation is nonexistent, but he's got a lot of unit tests in the project that show how to use it

Comment: Additional 3rd party you should is icshartziplib. Easy to use.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback. What I got to work was this http://aspalliance.com/1269_Zip_and_UnZip_files_in_C_using_J_libraries.2.